# asciidoctorj library does not work with Spring Boot 2 executable boot jar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle-plugin, asciidoctor

I am trying to use asciidoctorj with Spring Boot 2.0.3, everything works when I run project from IntelliJ IDEA, but when I create a boot jar, I started seeing the below error:

```
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- asciidoctor
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956) ~[jruby-complete-9.1.16.0.jar!/:na]
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55) ~[na:na]
    at RUBY.<main>(<script>:15) ~[na:na]
```

Here is snippet from by build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

... committed few lines

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

bootJar {
    launchScript()
    mainClassName = "com.example.demo.DemoApplication"
    requiresUnpack 'org.jruby:jruby-complete', 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj:1.5.7')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

My Project is hosted at, if someone wants to have a look at it

https://github.com/cancerian0684/spring-boot2-asciidoctorj

The same code used to work with Spring Boot 1.5.14 without issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Spring Boot's Gradle Plugin's [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-unpacking):

> To deal with any problematic libraries, an executable archive can be configured to unpack specific nested jars to a temporary folder when the executable archive is run. Libraries can be identified as requiring unpacking using Ant-style patterns that match against the absolute path of the source jar file.

The documentation then provides an example for matching `jruby-complete`:

```
bootJar {
    requiresUnpack '**/jruby-complete-*.jar'
}
```

The `**` means that the pattern will match irrespective of the directory that contains the jar. The jar's name is actually `jruby-complete-9.1.16.0.jar`, but the `*` in the pattern means that the pattern will match any version of the jar. An equivalent pattern for the AsciidoctorJ jar would be `**/asciidoctorj-*.jar`.

Putting this together, your `bootJar` task should be configured like this:

```
bootJar {
    launchScript()
    mainClassName = "com.example.demo.DemoApplication"
    requiresUnpack '**/jruby-complete*.jar', '**/asciidoctorj-*.jar'
}
```

To help with figuring out what the source path will be and, therefore, what an appropriate pattern would be, you can make use of the fact that `requiresUnpack` will also take a closure. From the documentation:

> For more control a closure can also be used. The closure is passed a `FileTreeElement` and should return a boolean indicating whether or not unpacking is required.

You could run your build with the following temporary configuration to see the paths of all of the files that are being added to the jar:

```
requiresUnpack {
    println it.file
    return false
}
```

You'll see output similar to the following:

```
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.0.3.RELEASE/41fd4180bea3813de8f3c602b5a126218360315b/spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.asciidoctor/asciidoctorj/1.5.7/8e8c1d8fc6144405700dd8df3b177f2801ac5987/asciidoctorj-1.5.7.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.0.3.RELEASE/2e389a8727588c549c28bb277f0f573f65554850/spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.0.3.RELEASE/ffaa050dbd36b0441645598f1a7ddaf67fd5e678/spring-boot-starter-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.0.3.RELEASE/25a51a75bfb997b7b95d6760178ee3303863ec4b/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.10.Final/4236051a8d209c00f85e70918d5e26d9f3e5201e/hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.7.RELEASE/751c871527ec7ff335ffc76f2e737e297c0a8d30/spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/5.0.7.RELEASE/2e04c6c2922fbfa06b5948be14a5782db168b6ec/spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jruby/jruby-complete/9.1.16.0/dfadacbdecc9c93a13871cc8242b92394d71631f/jruby-complete-9.1.16.0.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.beust/jcommander/1.35/47592e181b0bdbbeb63029e08c5e74f6803c4edd/jcommander-1.35.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.0.3.RELEASE/11bc4cc96b08fabad2b3186755818fa0b32d83f/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.0.3.RELEASE/b874870d915adbc3dd932e19077d3d45c8e54aa0/spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.0.3.RELEASE/7caad34f01d2688919e15e09a90467963e3d5190/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/5.0.7.RELEASE/243a23f8968de8754d8199d669780d683ab177bd/spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.0.7.RELEASE/fdd0b6aa3c9c7a188c3bfbf6dfd8d40e843be9ef/spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.0.7.RELEASE/c1196cb3e56da83e3c3a02ef323699f4b05feedc/spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/5.0.7.RELEASE/ca01fb473f53dd0ee3c85663b26d5dc325602057/spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.7.RELEASE/54b731178d81e66eca9623df772ff32718208137/spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/2d998d3d674b172a588e54ab619854d073f555b5/snakeyaml-1.19.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.6/456895fc91bf7180b216fead220373e6278230c9/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.6/ea54f6193d224e5e5732bbd4262327eb465397c2/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.6/129acd77a4b6ee30d62d3a0899b1344c8ec2bff8/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.6.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.6/cfa4f316351a91bfd95cb0644c6a2c95f52db1fc/jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.31/6564e716b89de5eaa0dd234ae7989576503ddf3/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.31/f5adf7ed8c34aa005b22b6a2dc7b6796e10e9c79/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.31/3a536e1ac71b82627c3a7408eb38fa0704cb9034/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.31.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/3789d00e859632e6c6206adc0c71625559e6e3b0/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.3.4/3d5f48f10bbe4eb7bd862f10c0583be2e0053c6/classmate-1.3.4.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.10.0/f7e631ccf49cfc0aefa4a2a728da7d374c05bd3c/log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/af5364cd6679bfffb114f0dec8a157aaa283b76/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jcl/5.0.7.RELEASE/699016ddf454c2c167d9f84ae5777eccadf54728/spring-jcl-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.6/4e393793c37c77e042ccc7be5a914ae39251b365/jackson-core-2.9.6.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.2.3/864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c/logback-core-1.2.3.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/da76ca59f6a57ee3102f8f9bd9cee742973efa8a/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.10.0/fec5797a55b786184a537abd39c3fa1449d752d6/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
```

It's these paths that the Ant-style patterns must match for a jar to be marked as requiring unpacking.